# Make rustc, cargo, rustup, rustdoc commands work without sudo inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, rust, debian, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a WSL Debian distro because I wanted to follow along with the InterMezzOS tutorials. I followed the installation instructions for Rust and ran `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`, but I can only make the `rustc` command available by running `source $HOME/.cargo/env` AFTER running `sudo su`, and when I exit `sudo` I can't call it, and when I retype `sudo su` it doesn't work anymore, I have to type it again.

Is there any way I can make it available so the commands work every time I open my shell, without running `sudo` every time?

Comment: *AFTER running `sudo su`* — why? What happens if you don't use `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: @Shepmaster it says "No such file or directory". I've tried doing `chown`, it says the same thing. I had to install Rust doing `sudo` too, it wouldn't let me do otherwise unless I added a "-y" flag, which I couldn't figure out how to make work. Is that part of the problem?

Comment: Why using sudo at all? Neither rustc, cargo, rustup, nor rustdoc need root. It's in fact dangerous to use root while compiling. (at least in the C world, not sure about Rust)

Comment: @hellow it gives me this error when I try to install using `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`: `error: $HOME differs from euid-obtained home directory: you may be using sudo
error: if this is what you want, restart the installation with `-y'`. I set my bash to open in my Windows folders automatically, is that part of the problem?

Comment: Note, you can always run cargo/rustc by using the full path

Comment: @hellow yes, but to do that every time would be really annoying...

Comment: Then please look at my first comment, the link to stackexchange

Comment: @hellow so would I just do `PATH=~/.home/env:$PATH`? Would it still say "No such file or directory?"

Comment: Because `~` always refers to the home of the current user. Use a full path instead.

Comment: @hellow Can you give me an example? When I `pwd` from `$~` it gives me this: `/mnt/c/Users/nebre/Desktop/Coding`.

Comment: `echo "$HOME/.cargo/bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile`. After that, reboot your pc (not sure when windows reads the profile) and it should work.

Comment: @hellow I just did that and rebooted. It says "-bash: /mnt/c/Users/nebre/Desktop/Coding/.cargo/bin: No such file or directory" right when I open the shell. Like I said, I can only access or even see the /.cargo/ folder in sudo mode. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible to compile a Rust program in the windows subsystem for linux ? Do you know that this feature of windows is limited ?

Comment: It works :) (for me™)

Comment: Not a solution, but: the IntermezzOS tutorials are somewhat based on a series of blog posts by Phil Oppermann, and he's working on a ['second edition'](https://os.phil-opp.com/second-edition/) which as far as I know doesn't require WSL - if you can't get things working, maybe give that a try instead.

Comment: @JoeClay I probably will, thanks! For now, I'm just running some commands in Git Bash and some in WSL; does anyone know of a way to make the commands in my Windows path work in WSL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right after you install Rust, you can find where it was installed in the Linux filesystem by running `whereis rustc`

It should output something like this:

```
rustc: /home/damianrivas/.cargo/bin/rustc
```

You need to add that to your path, so open up `.bashrc` in an editor

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

(if you use zsh like I do just replace it with `~/.zshrc`)

Scroll down to the bottom of the file (or use the keyboard shortcut `alt + /`, and add Rust's location to `PATH` by adding this at the end:

```
# Add Rust to $PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

I have `$HOME` because `/home/damianrivas/` is my `$HOME` path. I could've also put

```
export PATH="/home/damianrivas/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

After this is done, exit **all** of your open WSL terminals before opening up a new one. You can restart your PC to be sure. Then run `rustc --version` when you open up a new terminal and it should work.

Comment: I've never used `whereis` before, but the man page for it says (emphasis mine): *The whereis utility checks **the standard binary directories** for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.*. `rustc` *isn't* installed to a standard path. On macOS 10.13, `whereis rustc` does not print anything, while `rustc --version` does work. The more traditional method would be `which rustc`, which does work for me.

Comment: Rustup is already supposed to add the appropriate directory to the `PATH` variable; I have such an entry in `.bash_profile`. If you can reproduce behavior that it doesn't do that in WSL, that should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I believe my problem was that my $HOME directory in both WSL and in my Git Bash was the same, so my Linux Rust was overwriting my other one? Anyways, I fixed the problem by setting my home directory in WSL to a folder I created one level higher than my regular Git Bash Home directory.

Comment: I saw the discussion about adding rust to his path so I thought it was missing for him. @Ben, I'm glad you were able to get it working!

Comment: Also, `man whereis` shows me this: _whereis locates the binary, source and manual files for the specified command names._ I don't see any mention of "standard binary directories." Perhaps the command behaves differently in Ubuntu and maxOS? I did look at the man page for `which` and it does look like a generally better tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh` will add to `/home/<user>/.profile` a line that appends binaries in `~/.cargo/bin`, including rustup and rustc. The addition of the binaries in `.cargo` however does not take immediate effect. An easy way to associate it with your bash terminal is (immediately after installation):

```
echo $(cat ~/.profile | tail -1) >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

In your particular case, since you are root, you should copy `/root/home/.cargo` and `/root/home/.profile` into your own users home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Following their documentation I do this:

```
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

...


Current installation options:


   default host triple: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable (default)
               profile: default
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation


< I enter 1>
```

Then the installation completes with this:

```
Rust is installed now. Great!

To get started you may need to restart your current shell.
This would reload your PATH environment variable to include
Cargo's bin directory ($HOME/.cargo/bin).

To configure your current shell, run:
source $HOME/.cargo/env
```

So I do the following

- You may have to replace `~.bashrc` with `~/.zshrc` or something similar.

```
echo "export PATH='\$HOME/.cargo/bin:\$PATH'" >> ~/.bashrc"
source ~/.bashrc
```

And I check if rust is installed

```
$ whereis rustc
rustc: /usr/bin/rustc /usr/share/rustc /home/nvidia/.cargo/bin/rustc

$ which rustc
/home/nvidia/.cargo/bin/rustc

$ rustc --version
rustc 1.53.0 (53cb7b09b 2021-06-17)
```

This looks good, but now let's check out sudo so that system scripts can run without issues.

```
$ sudo whereis rustc
rustc:

$ sudo rustc --version
sudo: rustc: command not found
```

OMG! And this is how to fix it

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y rustc

$ sudo rustc --version
rustc 1.47.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#For Mac and Linux Users
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

#window users
Download rustup-init.exe from www.rustup.rs and run.

Note:#run this after
source $HOME/.cargo/env
```

To verify the current Rust version, use the rustc --version or rustc -V command.